# Update mysql query broken

Tags: php, mysql

My entire query was working fine, I changed the php dropdown part to get the list of asset 
numbers from the database, weirdly after those changes the update part does not want to work anymore... my apache2 error log complains about the undefined index who_out. I don't know what to change to get it working again...

Here is the current part that updates the asset with the necessary info.

```
$sql1=$_POST['fieldname']." AND '".$_POST['comments'];

if (strpos($_POST['comments'],'OUT') !== false) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE data SET ".$sql1."', dt_out = '$date', who_out = '".$_POST['who_out']."' WHERE data_id = '".$_POST['reference']."'";
} else {
    $sql2="UPDATE data SET ".$sql1."' WHERE data_id = '".$_POST['reference']."'";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql2,$con);
```

anyone able to assist me with what needs to change for this to work?
let me know if you need more info...

the original dropdown looked like this:

```
<td>Software Profile:</td>
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

$res02 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles");?>

<td>
<select name="swp">
<option selected="selected">Choose Profile</option>
<option></option>
<?php while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $res02 )) {                    
    $sel = ( data === $row['profile_id'] ) ? "id='sel' selected" : "";   
     printf ( " <option %s value='%s'>%s</option>\n", $sel, $row[1] , $row[1]);  //die data wat select en gedisplay word.
                      }; 

                      mysql_close($con);



?> 
</select>
```

the new drop down looks like this:

```
<td>Software Profile:</td>

<td>
        <select name="swp">
        <option selected>Select Profile...</option>
        <option value="no profile selected"></option>
            <?php
            $link=mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

            $query="SELECT profile_id, profile FROM profiles";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from Profiles Table failed: ".mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$profile=$row["profile"];
$profile_id=$row["profile_id"];
    echo "<option value=\"$profile\">$profile</option>";
}

            ?>

        </select>
```

and here is the form used to update a asset number if it has a status of !=OUT

```
<h2>Update Details:</h2>
<form action="updateref.php" method="post">
<table border="frame" align="center">
    <tr>
<td>Which Asset #:</td>
<td>
<select name="reference">
        <option selected>Select Asset #</option>
        <option></option>
            <?php
            $link=mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

            $query="SELECT * FROM data WHERE status != 'OUT'";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from Profiles Table failed: ".mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$data_id=$row["data_id"];
$asset=$row["asset"];
    echo "<option value=\"$asset\">$asset</option>";
} 
            ?>

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>What must be updated:</td>
<td>
<select name="fieldname">
<option selected="selected">Select Option</option>
<option value="asset">Asset Number</option>
<option value="make_model">Make Model</option>
<option value="os">Operating System</option>
<option value="office">Office</option>
<option value="swp">Software Profile</option>
<option value="ea">Extra Apps</option>
<option value="status">Status</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Change to:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="comments" required></input>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

</td>
<td>
<button id='sblogloginbtn' type="submit"><b>Update</b></button>  <button id='sblogloginbtn' type="reset" ><b>Reset</b></button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

how do i safetify the following code in the udpate.php page?

```
$sql1=$_POST['fieldname']."='".$_POST['comments'];


$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"]
$safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);




$who_out = $_POST['who_out'];
$reference = $_POST['reference'];
if (strpos($_POST['comments'],'OUT') !== false) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE data SET ".$sql1."', dt_out = '$date', who_out = '$who_out' WHERE asset = '$reference'";
} else {
    $sql2="UPDATE data SET ".$sql1."' WHERE asset = '$reference'";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql2,$con);
```

Comment: echo your query and check it once.. echo $sql2; exit();

Comment: Just an FYI, this code is horribly unsafe.

Comment: What does "changed the php dropdown" mean?  Are you sure `who_out` is getting POSTed?

Comment: "undefined index who_out" -- this means that `$_POST['who_out']` doesn't exist. Double-check your post form; you likely have a typo somewhere in the HTML.

Comment: replace your first line with `$sql1=$_POST['fieldname']."='".$_POST['comments'];`.

Comment: You mention you changed from something that was working to this drop down menu. Could you give the code you started out with.

Comment: You should give us a little bit more information as to the forms in which these are coming from. Where did you get who_out from? You might have a typo somewhere not listed in the code you pasted above or you may have used an incorrect attribute.

Comment: @Mr.Radical the dropdown that i changed and the update part of the website has nothing to do with one another. or atleast i believe so

Comment: @charlesisjan added more info in the question. added the dropdown changes as well as the form used to update

Comment: @RocketHazmat could you or anyone possibly give me a small example of how i would be able to use that mysql_real_escape in the example at the bottom of my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can not know what values your variables contain i can not help you very much.

Make a `echo $sql2;` at the end to show what the final query looks like. Then either you see the problem yourself or we can help - maybe one of your POST vars contains no or a wrong value.

ps: NEVER use POST directly in a query, always validate the input first. Read about "SQL Injection"...

Comment: When i do the echo $sql2; thing it give me this:

`UPDATE data SET status= 'OUT', dt_out = '2014-02-04 19:41:02', who_out = '' WHERE data_id = 'DT654322'`

Comment: @vamsi when closely studying the query, i noticed that on the signout form and the update form, the who_out is not added to the form to say who is updating/signing out this machine. added that and it works perfectly fine now without any errors.

Comment: could you eloborate on how i would go about NOT using POST in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

You probably changed the name of the input field from comments to something else. if you change it to this it shouldn't give you an error:
$sql1=$_POST['fieldname']." AND '".$_POST['comments'];

```
if (!empty($_POST['comments']) && strpos($_POST['comments'],'OUT') !== false) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE data SET ".$sql1."', dt_out = '$date', who_out = '".$_POST['who_out']."' WHERE data_id = '".$_POST['reference']."'";
} else {
    $sql2="UPDATE data SET ".$sql1."' WHERE data_id = '".$_POST['reference']."'";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql2,$con);
```